# Фильтры в GET запросе

Tags: java, spring

Как лучше всего реализовать фильтры в GET запросе?

Допустим есть метод,который получает пользователя с id равным 1: `/user?id=1`

Если нужно обрабатывать множество подобных фильтров `/user?id=1&name=Ivan&...` и не обязательно все будут использоваться.
Как лучше всего реализовать обработку?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = "RequestMethod.GET")
public String getUser(@RequestParam("name", required=false) String name) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Я бы делал так: `/user/:userId` - получить пользователя по айди, 
`/user/search?firstName=...&lastName=...` - поиск пользователя по имени, фамилии. Если нужно передать несколько параметров и некоторые из них не обязательные, то лучше конечно через query params (последний вариант) передавать.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще существует 3 способа передачи параметров запроса.

- в URL path
- Request Header
- Request Body

Для Get запроса доступны лишь 1 - 2 в силу отсутствия Body. Использовать 1 или 2 для не больших параметров (до 2048 символов в совокупности) кому как нравится. Если нужно больше, то вариант 2 и тот с оговоркой на используемые сервера

- Apache 2.0, 2.2: 8K
- nginx: 4K - 8K
- IIS: в зависимости от версии, 8K - 16K

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```java
// Вывод Заказчика по ID
    @GetMapping("/customer/{id}")
    Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return adminService.getCustomer(id);
    }
```

**Service:**

```java
// Вывод Заказчика по ID
    public Customer getCustomer(Long id) {
        return customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, User.ROLE_CUSTOMER).orElseThrow(() -> new MainNotFound(id));
    }
```